# primitive roots of composite numbers

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I am looking for a way to find primitive roots of composite numbers by primitive roots of its prime factors.im looking for a analytic way no algebraic.
I meant a way without meanings of abstract algebra like groups.
it is a great help if you help me with your links or files.

Comment: Composite numbers expcept for prime powers and twice a prime power do not admit a primitive root in the usual sense. It is thus unlclear what you want to know.

Comment: @quid so it is clear because of it.$2p^{k}$ is composite any way.

Comment: I do not understand your reply. For which numbers do you want  a primitive root?

Comment: @quid I meant we know primitive roots of primes,now we want to find primitive roots of p^2,p^3 and....other composite number,how we can find its primitive roots.

Comment: "other composite number" But they do not have primitive roots.

Comment: @quid.did you find what I mean?

Comment: For composite numbers, we may consider primitive root as an element of maximal order in the multiplicative group of $Z/NZ$.

Comment: @quid for example we know primitive root of 5 now how we can find primitive roots of 25 and 50?

Comment: This is explained in my answer. (Except that I made a typo.) Say you know taht $2$ is a prim root mode $5$. Then compote $2^{5-1}$ $\mod 5^2$. This is $16$ and not $1$. Thus $2$ is a primitive root for each number $5^r$. And $2 + 5^r$ is a primitive root mod $2 \ 5^r$.

Comment: @quid but you not $2.5^r$ has more primitive roots.right?can we talk on email?i don't have enough reputation for chat.

Comment: I do not understand what you are getting at. A prime also has more than one primitive root. Anyway if you have one, you can generate all others from it. $g^a $ with $a$ coprime to the order that is coprime to  $(p-1)p^{r-1}$

Comment: @quid can you give your email? I have some questions maybe you could help me.

Comment: Sorry, I do not do consulting by email. why not ask the question on this site.

Comment: @quid so look at my other questions please

Answer (score 1):

The only numbers that admit a primitive root are those of the form
$p^k$  and $2p^k$ with $p$ an odd prime, and $2$ and $4$.

Let's ignore the simple explicit cases $2$ and $4$.

Then we have the following paraphrased from [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n):

> If $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$, then $g$ is a primitive root modulo all powers $p^k$,  unless $g^{p – 1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$. In case $g^{p – 1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$ we have $g + p$ is primitive root.
>
> If $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p^k$, then $g$ or $g + p^k$ (whichever one is odd) is a primitive root modulo $2p^k$.

Thus, the problem is easily reduced to the one for primes.